# Rails 4.0 NEW app generates gem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, osx-mavericks

- Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks (Beta2)
- Ruby 2.0.0p195
- Rails 4.0.0

Used homebrew to install `rbenv` and `ruby-build`.  Installed Ruby `2.0.0p195` in the `~/.rbenv/versions` folder of my user folder.   Set to use this version *(not System ruby)*

When I run rails new APPNAME, I receive this error

```
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system: 
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.4) 
Using minitest (4.7.5) 
Using multi_json (1.7.7) 
Installing atomic (1.1.10) 
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/build_info/atomic-       1.1.10.info
An error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install atomic -v '1.1.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Any advice on how to solve this? The gem version is `2.0.3`.

Comment: Did you at any point in time use sudo to install any of the gems? or bundler?

Comment: Most likely, but newbie here so I don't have the exact command I may have used.  I had a good bit of trouble getting things installed and working up to this point.  I read over some of the install issues and tried a lot of things. Eventually got things working with rbenv to manage the versions since i was receiving a permission error when gems tried to install in the system ruby -- so went with rbenv to manage different versions so i wouldn't have any permission problems :)

Comment: The answer probably lies in `chown`

Comment: I'm not familiar with rbenv. I'm a `rvm` user and so far it's worked great.

Comment: Got the exact same problem...